# In zulip dev environment, how can i access zulip's first dev web browser using run-dev.py in vagrant env but i can't access from global ip

Tags: python, django, zulip

I have some problem now using zulip dev-env ...

I did success-installation by Dev-env(using run-dev.py in vagrant env) in my Mac PC and then i could access the first-dev page successfully through my mac-pc's browser
But i have been trying to show the first page using Dev-dev in my cloud hosting service (like AWS or google Cloud hosting) for several days 
but i could not access and could not show the first page by using global IP and browser

Which part must I change the setting environment?
(that is, I want to access my dev-env[using run-dev.py] by global IP
after that, i want to test... )

1. Now I am using a cloud hosting. Of course I opened port 9991 and etc...
2. I use `vagrant env` and succeed it in cloud host.

   In `vagrant ssh`, I could access zulip by using `curl 127.0.0.1:9991` and received a success message:

   > 29/Sep/2016 00:42:04]"GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 0"     from running console
3. but i cannot access it by host console like this

   ```
   ai2@mrtalk:~/project/zulip$ curl 127.0.0.1:9991
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9991: Connection refused
   ```

   of course , i can't access http://182.162.90.79:9991/ through my pc browser
4. for this I tried like these

   In `zproject/dev_setting.py` (I changed...these lines)

   ```
   EXTERNAL_HOST = '0.0.0.0:9991' #orgin localhost but change 0.0.0.0
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','182.162.90.79','0.0.0.0'] #orgin localhost but add + '182.162.90.79','0.0.0.0'
   ```

   In Vagrantfile I changed this line:

   ```
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9991, host: host_port, host_ip: 127.0.0.1, auto_correct: true
   ```

What is wrong with here? Or which part should I change my dev-setting?